# Slack Slash Command - inline image attachments

Tags: slack-api

I'm making a cribbage app for our slack channel. It's played using Slash commands. I'm currently showing the player their hand when they type the /showHand command, and it works, but I'd really like to be able to inline the image attachments but I cannot find a way to do this. Currently, it looks like this:
[image]

And if I use thumbnails it looks like this:
[image]

Is there a better approach? Possibly a way to add multiple images to one attachment? Possibly a display option to display response attachments inline?

UPDATE:
I followed Szymon Roziewski's advice and created a server-side module to download  the card images I needed and create the final image of the player's hand. The images are cached so they only need to be downloaded once during the lifetime of the dyno.
I also contacted Slack support and I was told that inlining image attachments isn't currently possible but they might make it a future feature.

Comment: I dont know whether it's possible, but you could quite easy merge two pics and then send to the player.

Comment: yeah? hint on how to do that?

Comment: You mean you develop your own app and then intergate with slack?

Comment: Yes, it's a node.js app hosted on Heroku that I've integrated via slash commands.

Comment: I guess, you know your cards, and what card is about to show up. Then you can merge those pics representing your cards and the subsequent one in js, and send one pic, is that possible with your setup?

Comment: I don't think so because the images are housed on AWS S3, all I'm doing is formatting the links to send back to the slack channel, no images actually live on my Heroku dynos.